# Symfony twig nl2br

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have twig template and rendering some data in this template, I have two variant

```
$datatest = "test" . chr(13) . "test"; //nl2br work good
$datatest = "test\ntest";//nl2br dosn't work, have string in template test\ntest
```

and second I have query builder, with select some field

```
        $qb
        ->select('
            CONCAT(TRIM(s.streetAddress), \'\\n\', s.postal, s.postOffice) as company_address
        ')
```

I try

```
        $qb
        ->select('
            CONCAT(TRIM(s.streetAddress), CHAR(13), s.postal, s.postOffice) as company_address
        ')
```

but query builder have error, don't find function CHAR(13), how to create custom DQL for CHAR(13) ?

and in template when `dump(data)` have string but nl2br not work

[image]

I try another filter twig, like this

```
            <div style="font-size: 8px;">
            {{ data.company_name|upper }}<br>
            {% set address = data.company_address|nl2br %}
            {{ address|upper|raw }}
        </div>

        <br>

        <div style="font-size: 9px;">
            {{ datatest|nl2br }}
        </div>
```

what need to do in select for nl2br work fine??

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't format the output inside the SQL query. You're using an MVC framework, so you should definitely stay within it's concepts - let the presentation be done in the view (a.k.a. template).

I recommend select and present tha data this way:

Model:

```
$qb->select('s.streetAddress, s.postal, s.postOffice')->from ...
```

Template:

```
{{ streetAddress }}<br>
{{ postal }} {{ postOffice }}
```

Comment: I want using nl2br, and add break line in select

Comment: But why would you do that? Try to explain what are the reasons for do it that way. We, developers, are trying to find reusable solutions. If you lock the formating inside your query and then, for example, you'll need only streetAddress somewhere else in your app, what are you gonna do? Another query? As you can see, other 3 people upvoted this answer, so the opinion seems to be right not only for me...

Comment: I understand but I want realize this approach add break line in select and using nl2br in twig and not understand not this work